# changing panel colors

Tags: c#

I created a simple code here just to play around with C#. It has 3 buttons and 1 panel. If you click on the 2nd & 3rd button the panel height changes. Is that also possible to change the color?

For example, if I click on the 2nd button, I would like to have it as yellow and at the same time the height changes as well, and the same with 3rd button.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
public int heightPanel;

  public Form1()
    {
  InitializeComponent();
  heightPanel = panel1.Height;
    }

  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
  panel1.Height = heightPanel;
    }

  private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
  panel1.Height = this.Height/2;
    }

  private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
  panel1.Height = this.Height - 150;
    }
  }
```

I have an idea but I don't know where to put this. I think it would be something like this:

```
panel1.Height=this.BackColor.ToString();
```

Any inputs?

### Response to reply

Yes, I would like to retain the 3 colors if I click in any of the button. I'm not sure if it's possible. For ex:

```
my button1 =pink
button2=yellow
button3=green
```

If I click on the button 1 I'll see the pink color, and if I click on the button2 I'll see the pink and yellow.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All you'd need to do would be to set the `BackColor` on a new line. For instance...

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Height = this.Height/2;
    panel1.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.Height = this.Height - 150;
    panel1.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
}
```

Comment: thanks it works.But I would like to retain the old color. For example, I put yellow to the button2.So that means if I click on the button3 (which has green color)I would like to retain the color of the button2 which is yellow.That means,there would be 2colors now.Is that possible?

Comment: Why don't you edit your post to show exactly what you mean. No, it's not possible to set the BackColor to two colors (not sure what might be the expected effect of that...), but I doubt that's what you actually want to do.

Answer (score 1):

Simple as:

```
panel1.BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Answer (score 0):

In `button2_Click`, just add another line like this:

```
panel1.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
```